# Installation of AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver fails

Tags: 11.04, fglrx

Installation of AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver fails on 11.04 which was upgraded from 10.10

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libknewstuff2-4 libqt4-test kdesudo libqt4-help python-qt4 python-sip libvncserver0 libqtassistantclient4 update-manager-kde libqt4-scripttools python-kde4
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/40,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 124 MB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56859 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56860 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Config-Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/available' near line 59749 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
(Reading database ... 511988 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking fglrx (from .../fglrx_2%3a8.840-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56859 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56860 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Config-Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56859 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56860 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Config-Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56859 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56860 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Config-Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56859 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56860 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Config-Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56859 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56860 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Config-Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56859 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56860 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Config-Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56859 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56860 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Config-Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56859 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56860 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Config-Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56859 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number
dpkg-divert: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 56860 package 'virtualbox-2.2':
 error in Config-Version string '2.2.4-47978_Ubuntu_jaunty': invalid character in revision number

[Warning] Uninstall : inst_path_default or inst_path_override
 does not exist in /etc/ati.  This suggests that the ATI driver
 is not installed, the ATI driver is only partially installed,
 or the current ATI driver installed is an older version than the
 one this script was designed for.  Both files listed above are
 required for determining where installed files are located.
 To force uninstallation of the driver by guessing where the
 uninstallation files are located, set the FORCE_ATI_UNINSTALL
 environment variable and re-run /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh (this is not recommended).

dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a8.840-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
Selecting previously deselected package fglrx-amdcccle.
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle (from .../fglrx-amdcccle_2%3a8.840-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx_2%3a8.840-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: go on - give us a hint - what failed, error messages - anything about your computer, what have you tried, what were you doing.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the fglrx driver and then reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx
```

Then you can either install fglrx again from the Ubuntu repos or use the fglrx installer script that the Kanotix distro's leader wrote.

If you choose to install  from the Ubuntu repos, just run

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

If you choose to use the Kanotix script, which I highly recommend (it downloads the latest fglrx driver and contains patches to support newer kernel versions):

```
cd /tmp
wget http://kanotix.net/files/install-fglrx-debian.sh
chmod +x install-fglrx-debian.sh
```

Then press Control + Alt + F2. You will be put in a TTY. Login with your username and password, then run

```
cd /tmp
sudo ./install-fglrx-debian.sh
```

Comment: when i used the script, everything just got messed, i don't know why  it gave me lots of error during the installation of the driver.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `dpkg` status is highly corrupted. (many lines of `dpkg-divert` warnings)

Try:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad

sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

in Terminal. Reboot, and try the installation again. If it fails, do the entire procedure at:
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure

I've had this issue before, and it really helps.

Comment: Oh, and try(as per @ChenXiaoLong 's answer) `sudo apt-get purge flgrx` after trying my commands I gave.